# What is the equivalent of memset in Forth?

Tags: forth

If I need to fill an array with a single value, is there a typical Forth word to do something like what `memset` from C does (that is, set a region of bytes to a specific value)?

Answer (score 2):

In the Forth standard, the word for initializing raw memory is `ERASE`, which is in the Core Extensions word set:

> `ERASE` ( *addr* *u* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, clear all bits in each of *u* consecutive address units of memory beginning at *addr*.

`ERASE`, as its name suggests, only clears/zeroes memory.

There is also `FILL`, in the Core word set, for setting consecutive characters:

> `FILL` ( *c-addr* *u* *char* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, store *char* in each of *u* consecutive characters of memory beginning at *c-addr*.

However, the standard does **not** require characters to be one address unit in size.

If you just want to set a range of address units to a value other than zero, then that is not really a portable or standard compliant operation anyway, so just use `FILL` if your address unit is the same size as a character (as it is in most Forths).

The standard also provides `BLANK`, in the String word set, for setting a string to spaces:

> `BLANK` ( *c-addr* *u* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, store the character value for space in *u* consecutive character positions beginning at *c-addr*.